# Detect collision with Sprite-Sheet animation

Tags: c#, xna, sprite-sheet

How detect collision with sprite animation?

SpriteManager.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using System.IO;
namespace Mini
{
    public class SpriteManager
    {
        protected Texture2D Texture;
        public Vector2 Position = Vector2.Zero;
        protected Dictionary<string, AnimationClass> Animations =
            new Dictionary<string, AnimationClass>();
        protected int FrameIndex = 0;
        protected Vector2 Origin;

        private int height;
        private int width;
        private string animation;
        public string Animation
        {
            get { return animation; }
            set
            {
                animation = value;
                FrameIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get { return height; }
        }

        public int Width
        {
            get { return width; }
        }

        public Rectangle Rectangle
        {
            get { return Animations[Animation].Rectangles[FrameIndex]; }
        }

        public Texture2D Texture2D
        {
            get { return Texture; }
        }


        public SpriteManager(Texture2D Texture, int Frames, int animations)
        {
            this.Texture = Texture;
            width = Texture.Width / Frames;
            height = Texture.Height / animations;
            Origin = new Vector2(width / 2, height / 2);
        }

        public void AddAnimation(string name, int row, 
            int frames, AnimationClass animation)
        {
            Rectangle[] recs = new Rectangle[frames];
            Color[][] frameImageData = new Color[frames][];
            Texture2D[][] frameImage = new Texture2D[frames][];
            for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
            {
                recs[i] = new Rectangle(i * width, 
                    (row - 1) * height, width, height);
                frameImageData[i] = new Color[width  * height];
            }
            animation.Frames = frames;
            animation.Rectangles = recs;
            Animations.Add(name, animation);
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position,
                Animations[Animation].Rectangles[FrameIndex],
                Animations[Animation].Color,
                Animations[Animation].Rotation, Origin,
                Animations[Animation].Scale,
                Animations[Animation].SpriteEffect, 0f);
        }


        public bool IntersectPixels(SpriteManager b)
        {
            Rectangle rectangleA = this.Rectangle;
            Rectangle rectangleB = b.Rectangle;
            int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
            int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
            int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
            int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);
            Color[] dataA = new Color[rectangleA.Width * rectangleA.Height];
            this.Texture.GetData(0, rectangleA, dataA, 0, rectangleA.Width * rectangleA.Height);


            Color[] dataB = new Color[rectangleB.Width * rectangleB.Height];
            b.Texture.GetData(0, rectangleB, dataB, 0, b.Width * b.Height);
            Stream s = File.Create("t.png"); 
            b.Texture2D.SaveAsPng(s, rectangleB.Width, rectangleB.Height);

            for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
            {
                for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
                {
                    Color colorA = dataA[(x - rectangleA.Left) + (y - rectangleA.Top) * rectangleA.Width];
                    Color colorB = dataB[(x - rectangleB.Left) + (y - rectangleB.Top) * rectangleB.Width];
                    if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


    }
}
```

With this code, the collision is detected every few frames of animation anywhere
`IntersectPixels` is to detect collisions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what kind of collision you're trying ot manage? As far as I understand by your code, a simple "rectangle1.Intersects(rectangle2);" should suffice.

Comment: I'm interested in a collision per pixel